# Selenium error message

Tags: selenium

I was getting the below error when running scripts

Problem while capturing system stateundefined local variable or method `selenium_driver' for Spec::Example::ExampleGroup::Subclass_1:0x7f8ad0819298>

here is my settings :

> def sel_setup
>       @verification_errors = []

```
if $selenium
  @selenium = $selenium
else
  @selenium = Selenium::Client::Driver.new "localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://xyz.com", 5000000  
  @selenium.start_new_browser_session  
end
@selenium.set_context("Executing XYZ test cases")
```

end

> def test_stop
>      @selenium.close_current_browser_session
>    end

Could any one please tell me the fix on this issue .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSpec HTML report formatter that comes with the selenium-client gem needs `selenium_driver` to point to your instance of `Selenium::Client::Driver`.

In your case, something like this should work:

```
def selenium_driver
  @selenium
end
```